# The powers that be

Tags: etymology, idioms

How did the phrase **"the powers that be"** come about, is it an archaic verb tense of "being"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the phrase comes from the King James Bible:

[Romans 13:1](http://www.bibletools.org/index.cfm/fuseaction/Bible.show/sVerseID/28268/eVerseID/28271) (King James Version): *Let every soul be subject unto the higher powers. For there is no power but of God: **The powers that be** are ordained of God.*

"That be" means simply "that exist."

Comment: I might just add that it is an example of the formulaic subjunctive.

Comment: That is, its use today is the formulaic subjunctive, not that its original use in the KJV was.

Comment: Yes, and I suppose something similar could be said of all formulaic subjunctives.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: Actually, it doesn't seem to have originated as a subjunctive use: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/297574/77227