# Grammar, Meaning of Following Sentence

Tags: meaning

> The corporate powers that be had decided last minute that I couldn't
> interview two key figures or use their information due to
> confidentiality issues and pre-IPO precautions.

This writer of the sentence above is working on an academic paper under extreme time pressures.

I am facing difficulty in determing which is the verb and subject of the main clause.
Please provide a grammatical and semantic explanation.

Comment: See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/297497/277451) for an explanation of the phrase “powers that be”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the main clause is your entire sentence

> *The corporate powers that be had decided last minute that I couldn't interview two key figures or use their information due to confidentiality issues and pre-IPO precautions.*

It's clear that the subject of the sentence is **The corporate powers that be** and its verb is **had decided.**

On a separate note, *the corporate powers that be* uses **the subjunctive** (in case this is what's confusing  you. )

I would further suggest you'd better slightly modify your sentence as:

> The corporate powers that be had decided **at the** last minute that I couldn't interview two key figures or use their information due to confidentiality issues and pre-IPO precautions.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation.  Now, I have totally comprehended the sentence structure--it turned out the problem was the phrase "the powers that be." Regarding the suggestion, I had assumed "last minute" was shorthand for that idiomatic phrase as well. The writer of the sentence in question is American--but not a professional writer, so may occasionally use words sloppily. Can you provide a bit more of explanation on this?

Comment: @user48754: Well, I guess I'll have to retract my words. I mean it's okay to omit the preposition sometimes and here too it's a matter of style whether you wish to keep or omit **at.** The sentence reads just as fine in both cases.

Comment: Thank you. I now understand everything.